# How can I split the first child into a full-length column on the left, and display the rest of the children on the right?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to display the first item of the `<aside>` tag centered at the left.
All other items should be displayed on the right.

I'm using a tool (asciidoctor-html5s) to convert asciidoc to html5.
Therefore I cannot change the HTML.

This is the generated HTML:

```html
<aside class="admonition-block tip" role="doc-tip">
    <h6 class="block-title">
        <span class="title-label">Tip: </span>
        Info
    </h6>
    <p>Go to this URL to learn more about it:</p>
    <div class="ulist">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="bare" href="http://asciidoc.org">http://asciidoc.org</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <p>Or you could return to the <a href="#first">First Steps</a> or <a href="#purpose">Purpose</a>.</p>
</aside>
```

And this is an example how it should look like:

[image: target look]

Is this possible and if yes, how?

Please do not focus on the `Info` text inside the `h6`. I know this is not possible. The question is centered around having the first item on the left an all n other items on the right.

Comment: Not possible with standard layout options given your HTML structure.

Comment: You can't split the `h6` like that. Your only real option is absolute positioning of "TIP".

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I edited my question to include the fact that the split of the `h6` is not the main question ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `float: left` and a bit styling to the `height` and `margin-right`

```css
.admonition-block .block-title {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  height: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<aside class="admonition-block tip" role="doc-tip">
  <h6 class="block-title">
    <span class="title-label">Tip: </span>
    Info
  </h6>
  <p>Go to this URL to learn more about it:</p>
  <div class="ulist">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="bare" href="http://asciidoc.org">http://asciidoc.org</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p>Or you could return to the <a href="#first">First Steps</a> or <a href="#purpose">Purpose</a>.</p>
</aside>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but your method works only if you know how high the element has to be. In my case I don't know how high it will be because it's dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

If your HTML is going to be exactly like that (e.g. an `h6`, a `p`, a `div`, and then another `p`), then you can hard code it like this using a combination of CSS Grid and CSS Flexbox styles:

```css
aside {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50px 320px; /* picked these sizes at random; feel free to change */
    grid-gap: 5px; /* picked these sizes at random; feel free to change */
}
aside > * {
    grid-column: 2;
}
h6 {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1 / 5;
    display: flex;
    visibility: hidden;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
h6 span {
    visibility: visible;
}
p::before {
    content:"Info";
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    font-style: italic;
}
aside p:first-of-type {
    grid-row: 1;
}
aside div {
    grid-row: 2;
}
aside p:last-of-type {
    grid-row: 3;
}
```

```html
<aside class="admonition-block tip" role="doc-tip">
    <h6 class="block-title">
        <span class="title-label">Tip: </span>
        Info
    </h6>
    <p>Go to this URL to learn more about it:</p>
    <div class="ulist">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="bare" href="http://asciidoc.org">http://asciidoc.org</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <p>Or you could return to the <a href="#first">First Steps</a> or <a href="#purpose">Purpose</a>.</p>
</aside>
```

I hid the "Info" text node in markup and added it in CSS as a pseudo-element. It's not selectable that way, but the trade of is it can be positioned the way you want it to.

Maybe there is a way in your converter software to disallow naked text nodes like that (it's considered bad practice to have atomic text not wrapped in an element if you want to style/select it).

Comment: Thanks for your example. The elements are not always the same. The only thing that is constant is the `<aside>` and the first `<h6><span>...`. The rest is flexible and depends on the content to render from asciidoc.